# Pyspark UDF - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to run the following code based on some tutorial I found online:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions
from pyspark.sql import udf
df_pd = pd.DataFrame(
data={'integers': [1, 2, 3],
 'floats': [-1.0, 0.5, 2.7],
 'integer_arrays': [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]}
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)
df.show()

def square(x):
    return x**2
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
square_udf_int = udf(lambda z: square(z), IntegerType())
```

But when I run the last line I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I am using spark 2.3.3 on Hadoop 2.7.

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling the udf function! can you tell?

Comment: @RAMSHANKERG I dont really understand what you mean, in the last line before the error as my message says I'm trying to convert my  function to an UDF, that is all the code I'm running with the error   square_udf_int = udf(lambda z: square(z), IntegerType())

Comment: Shouldn't you send some value to z by calling the square_udf_int function?

Comment: @RAMSHANKERG Yes, when I call the UDF; but the code fails when declaring it

Comment: Include the full traceback that shows the exact code causing the error. Somewhere you have a `()` that doesn't belong.

Comment: Well your `udf` is a module and you cannot call it. What else do you expect and why? Did you take a look at the relevand documentation?

Answer (score 10):

it seems you're importing from `pyspark.sql` while it should be `pyspark.sql.functions`
like...

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

     udf_fun = F.udf (lambda..., Type())
```